# Modular fractions: $5 \big| 3- \frac 12$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

I've read a lot here about how modular fractions are valid as long as the denominator is invertible, but they always cause me trouble understing this part:

From the definition of congruence:

$$
a \equiv b \pmod m \iff m \big |a-b
$$

And $\frac 1 2\equiv \frac 6 2 \equiv 3 \pmod 5$ So I can say $5$ divides $2,5$?

Comment: $5 \nmid \frac{5}{2}$

Comment: I know that, I was just saying that's a consequence of accepting 'fractions' in mod arithmetic.

Comment: Mod 5, the difference should be 0, and it indeed is: 3 - 1/2 = 5/2 = 0

Comment: This notation shouldn't be employed, as it is quite confusional. There can be no fractions here. What is true is that $2$ has an inverse modulo $5$, and this inverse is $3$ since $2\cdot 3\equiv 1\mod5$, it should be denoted $2^[-1}$.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD.  Your definition of congruence pertains to integers, not rationals.  The expression $\frac{1}{2}$ mod (5) does not refer to the rational number "$\frac{1}{2}$" but rather to a natural number b such that 2b = 1 mod(5).  This congruence has solution b = 3 mod (5) (since 6 = 1 mod (5)) but this does not mean that the rational number $\frac{1}{2}$ = 3 in any sense.